# ATSFontGetFileReference error when running wkhtmltopdf (qt) as nobody

Tags: php, qt, fonts, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/), which is based on Qt, to generate PDF versions of a local web page. So far it does exactly what I need it to when I run it directly from the command line. For example, this works:

`wkhtmltopdf http://localhost/~acobster/foo/?render=1 ~/Desktop/foo.pdf`

However, when I try to call it from a PHP script, it fails. It seems to have to do with running as `nobody`, since

`sudo -u nobody wkhtmltopdf http://localhost/~acobster/foo/?render=1 ~/Desktop/foo.pdf`

causes it to spit out this error about a hundred times:

> wkhtmltopdf[45642] : ATSFontGetFileReference failed: error
>   -120. Qt: internal: -108: Error ATSUMeasureTextImage text/qfontengine_mac.mm: 1136

I believe it's complaining about not being able to render the font "Palatino," which I specify in a CSS font-family rule within the page. But even if I replace Palatino with Times and run again as nobody, I get this:

```
QPainter::begin(): Returned false
```

Why would I be able to process this font as my regular user but not as `nobody`? Is there something about Qt that doesn't play nicely with that user?

Comment: Not knowing anything about what or why; could there be a paths issue?

Comment: It could be, but I'm not sure how to tell. Could you please be more specific?